# Random error on application run

Tags: android, eclipse

alright, weird problem here.

Cant figure out how to solve it...

My app has been running awesome until it randomly said there was an error while running. Like, it will be fine but as soon as i hit run, it will stop and say the project contains errors. But it doesn't. I have even cleaned and closed the project. See pic below...

Any ideas!?!?

[image]

Comment: What shows up in the "Problems" tab? *Something* is wrong.

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type Error generating final archive: Debug Certificate expired on 12/5/11 10:06 PM Omega Launcher Recovered  Unknown Android Packaging Problem

Comment: Looks like whatever omega launcher is has expired.

Comment: Thats right. I just figured it out, now i cant find (mac)--> ~/.android/debug.keystore

Answer (score 0):

Check your error log. It should be in one of the tabs where LogCat is. It should tell you exactly where the problem is.

Alternatively, expend your projects folders until you locate the file that has the red X box on it, that file contains an error if it's

Comment: It says, Description Resource Path Location Type
Error generating final archive: Debug Certificate expired on 12/5/11 10:06 PM Omega Launcher Recovered  Unknown Android Packaging Problem

Comment: See this: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

    To fix this problem, simply delete the debug.keystore file. The default storage location for AVDs is in ~/.android/ on OS X and Linux, in C:\Documents and Settings\.android\ on Windows XP, and in C:\Users\.android\ on Windows Vista and Windows 7.

Comment: Thanks guys! Another temporary solution is to just set your computers date back, which i did for the night real quick, but doing the above method is what i did the next day and works great!